# Connect to MySql DB using mysql.connector

Tags: python, mysql

I am using mysql.connector to connect to a mysql DB, while i can connect manually to the db using sql server management, if i try connecting via code, it returns this error after awhile :

```
mysql.connector.errors.OperationalError: 2055: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'host:1234', system error: 10054 An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

These are the connection details :

```
connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='host',
                                 port = '1234',
                                 database='DBname',
                                 user='Usr',
                                 password='pwd')
```

If I create a local mysql DB, the connection works just fine. 
I assume some security stuff is going on, anyone else had encountered this situation ? Anything that I'm doing wrong? Should I add anything to the connection.connect input ?

Full code for reference :

```
    import mysql.connector

from mysql.connector import Error

connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='host',
                                     port = '1234',
                                     database='DBname',
                                     user='Usr',
                                     password='pwd')

sql_select_Query = "select * from TableName"
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql_select_Query)
records = cursor.fetchall()
print("Total numb of rows selected is : ", cursor.rowcount)

print("\nPrinting each row")
for row in records:
    print(row)

connection.close()
```

Comment: What do your database logs say?

Comment: your problem description saying that you're connecting to mysql database using sql server management.(Correct if it's wrong). In case , you're connecting to mysql using ssms - I believe you need to configure linked server  https://www.devart.com/odbc/mysql/docs/microsoft_sql_server_manager_s.htm . Have you done so?